# Calling function of a subclass of Immutable.Map throws 'xxx is not a function' exception

Tags: immutable.js

I have created a new class this way:

```
import Immutable from 'immutable';

export default class Faq extends Immutable.Map {

  getState(faqNum) {
    return this.get(faqNum) || false;
  }

  setState(faqNum, open) {
    return this.set(faqNum, open);
  }
}
```

But when I call `getState` on an instance of `Faq`, it throws an exception `faqState.getState is not a function` exception?

Why it does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out `Immutable-js` does not support class inheritance. (https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/issues/301)